# STM32F030K6T6 Timer 1 PWM CH2N not Working

Tags: stm32, hal

i using Timer 1 and set PWM on CH1 and CH2N

CH1 is work fine

but CH2N not working (i checked pin work fine on nromal GPIO)

my code only have two line :

HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

anyone help me ?

void MX_TIM1_Init(void)

{

TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};

TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

htim1.Instance = TIM1;

htim1.Init.Prescaler = 85;

htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;

htim1.Init.Period = 10000;

htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;

htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;

htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;

if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;

if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;

sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;

if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM2;

sConfigOC.Pulse = 5000;

sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;

sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;

sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;

sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;

sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;

if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;

sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;

if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)

{

Error_Handler();

}

HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two functions you need to use.
In my case it is 2 PWM on tim1 channel_3

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);    //starts PWM on CH2 pin  TIM1
HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3); //starts PWM on CH1N pin TIM1
```

In your case it should be:

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
```